# Adding missing zeroes in the begining of each line where is less than 4 signs

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I would ask you how to solve this problem:
I need to prepend 0s to every line where the word has less than 4 letters.

Example input file:

```
30
1
508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

Desired output should be:

```
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

Many thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: you can use `awk+printf`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html#Format-Modifiers and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Comment: @Sundeep, not the easiest approach when the input is in hexadecimal like here.

Comment: Are those values stored in a file or in a shell array or already being read in a shell loop for some other reason or something else? Are they hex numbers or something else? Do you ever have input strings already longer than 4 chars and, if so, should they be truncated some way or left as-is?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh, I didn't realize awk didn't have a way to zero fill a string

Answer (score 5):

You could add 4 leading zeros to all lines, and then get the 4 last characters of each:

```
sed 's/^/0000/; s/^.*\(.\{4\}\)/\1/' < file
```

Or to avoid truncating numbers that were more than 4 digits wide in the first place:

```
sed 's/^/0000/; s/^.\{1,4\}\(.\{4\}\)/\1/' < file
```

Comment: nice. "sed 's/^/0000/; s/^.*\(.\{4\}\)/\1/' < file" working perfect

Answer (score 3):

One more for the mix:

```
$ numfmt --format='%04.0f' --invalid=ignore < file
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

`numfmt` is provided by the GNU Coreutils package.

Comment: That doesn't pad the numbers that have A-F digits though.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for strtonum() if your input is hex numbers:

```
$ awk '{printf "%04X\n", strtonum("0x"$0)}' file
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

With GNU awk whether your input is hex or not:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/ /,0,"g",sprintf("%4s",$0))}' file
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

With any awk whether your input is hex or not:

```
$ awk '{v=sprintf("%4s",$0); gsub(/ /,0,v); print v}' file
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
```

or even:

```
$ awk '{$0=sprintf("%4s",$0); gsub(/ /,0)} 1' file
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant way:

```
cat file | sed 's/^\(...\)$/0\1/' | sed 's/^\(..\)$/00\1/' | sed 's/^\(.\)$/000\1/'
```

Comment: You don't need to pipe sed's output into another sed, at least not when you're just doing a series of simple transformations.  You can use multiple `-e` arguments, or you can just use a semi-colon to separate sed commands.  e.g. `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/abc/xyz'` or `sed -e 's/foo/bar/; s/abc/xyz/'`.  You don't need the `cat`, either - sed can read file(s) by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are inside the shell already and are all hex numbers:

```
$ set -- 30 1 508 A0EA A0EB A0EC A0ED
$ for var; do printf '%04X\n' "0x$var"; done
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

If the values of a line could be any string (even longer than 4 characters) and `line` contains the value(s) of a line, the solution becomes more complex:

```
[ "${#line}" -lt 4 ] && 
    printf '%0*d%s\n' "$((4-${#line}))" 0 "$line" || 
        printf '%s\n' "${line}"
```

will print the value with as many zeros as needed to make the string 4 characters long.

Then, for an external file (sed and awk solutions are faster for external files), make a loop and expand the code to make it more legible as:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [ "${#line}" -lt 4 ]; then 
        printf '%0*d%s\n' "$((4-${#line}))" 0 "$line"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "${line}"
    fi
done <file
```

Comment: Nice work with mixing couple of functions.

Comment: That will be extremely slow, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Probably at least an order of magnitude slower than the sed or awk solutions.

Comment: Yes, Ed, that is true. Well, but only for an external file. If the values are in the shell already in a variable like `line`, this is faster.

Comment: Good point, the OP didn't say either way so for all we know he has a shell array of values and is looping through them already for other reasons in which case you would not want to call sed or awk for each value separately. We should have asked some questions before jumping to posting answers - I've added a comment below the question now.

Answer (score 0):

With the `zsh` shell, you can use the `l:length::string:` left-padding parameter expansion flag.

```
$ var=FF
$ echo ${(l:4::0:)var}
00FF
```

To apply it on each word in a file:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(l:4::0:)$(<file)}
```

Note that that operator also *truncates* words larger than 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ne 'printf "%05s", $_' ip.txt
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```

Using `5` instead of `4` here, as there's also a newline character in each line. Lines with more than 5 characters will be printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

Using Posix sed:

```
  sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{0,3\}$/0&/;ta'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda lame, (files must be shorter than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes), but it works:

```
printf '%4s\n' $(<file) | tr ' ' 0
```

Comment: Just use `'%04s\n'` and drop `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | awk -vlen=4 '{
  add=""          #empty prefix to be added

  if(length($1)!=len){
       for(i=(len-length($1));i<=length($1);i++)
           add=add"0"          #add prefix as necessary
  }

  print $1""add

 }'
```

Feel free to change the variable `len` to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` on macOS or FreeBSD:

```
xargs printf '%04s\n' < file
```

This runs `printf` with arguments from `file` to the limit of command line arguments per call to `printf`.

Use `sed` on Linux and the *BSD:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\)$/000\1/' -e 's/^\(..\)$/00\1/' -e 's/^\(...\)$/0\1/'
```

Short and efficient.

Comment: What printf implementation does 0-padding with `%04s`? With the `printf` implementations I tried I get either the same as `%4s` (space padding) or an error.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the catch, printf functionality differs between *BSD and Linux. So I clarified that and added a sed version a one command (no pipes).

Answer (score -1):

I have done by using if condition and awk

```
count_line=`awk '{print NR}' p.txt| sed -n '$p'`

for ((i=1;i<=$count_line;i++)); do j=`awk -v i="$i" -F "" 'NR==i{print NF}' p.txt`; if [[ $j == "1" ]]; then awk -v i="$i" -F "" 'NR==i{print "000"$0}' p.txt; elif [[ $j == "2" ]]; then awk -v i="$i" -F "" 'NR==i{print "00"$0}' p.txt ; elif [[ $j == "3" ]]; then awk -v i="$i" -F "" 'NR==i{print "0"$0}' p.txt; else awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $0}' p.txt; fi; done
```

output

```
0030
0001
0508
A0EA
A0EB
A0EC
A0ED
```